# getFinancials() not working?

Tags: r, quantmod

I just tried `getFinancials("GOOG")` from the `quantmod` package and I have run into errors whilst downloading the data. Yesterday this worked without problem.

Has anybody else ran into the same problem?

```
Error in download.file(paste(google.fin, Symbol, sep = ""), quiet = TRUE,  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://finance.google.com/finance?fstype=ii&q=GOOG'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste(google.fin, Symbol, sep = ""), quiet = TRUE,  :
  cannot open URL 'http://finance.google.com/finance?fstype=ii&q=GOOG': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

`getSymbols("GOOG")` works perfectly fine for me.

**EDIT:** It seems that Google has droped this functionality. See the following [link](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/221) for future reference.

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Strange, I will check my connection settings in R

Comment: For future references. https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/221#issuecomment-375925018